# CustomAuthorizeAttribute redirects to LoginView even when the user is logged in (ASP.Net MVC 5)

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-mvc-5, loginview, authorize-attribute

For my studies I have to implement a custom AuthorizeAttribute to allow or not users to access parts of the application in function of their roles (admin, manager, ...). I'm using my own SQL DB.

Could you please help me understand why it redirects to LoginView even when the user is logged in?
I searched a lot on the web but didn't found any solution.

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Authentication/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

AuthenticationController:

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(User user, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (IsValid(user.Email, user.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, true);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect Email or Password.");
                return View(user);
            }
        }
        return View(user);
    }

    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    private bool IsValid(string email, string password)
    {
        var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

        bool isValid = false;

        using (var dBContext = new DBContext())
        {
            var user = dBContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);

            if (user!=null)
            {
                if (user.Password == crypto.Compute(password, user.saltedPassword))
                {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
 }
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager,...")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Filter:

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public CustomAuthorizeAttribute() { }
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        DBContext dBContext = new DBContext();

        var roleList = from r in dBContext.Roles
            join rl in dBContext.RoleLists on r.RoleId equals rl.RoleId
            join s in dBContext.Subscriptions on rl.SubscriptionId equals s.SubscriptionId
            join u in dBContext.Users on s.UserId equals u.UserId
            where u.Email == httpContext.User.Identity.Name
            select r.RoleName;

        foreach (string definedRole in this.Roles.Split(','))
        {
            foreach (string role in roleList)
            {
                if (definedRole.Equals(role))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

FilterConfig:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

**Edit to add more info:**

If I use as return value true for AuthorizeCore():
At the first iteration of the foreach this.Roles doesn't contain the defined roles but at the second iteration well ... the system displays the requested view without taking the defined roles in consideration.

If I use as return value false for AuthorizeCore():
The iteration of the first foreach happens only one time and this.Roles doesn't contain the defined roles, the second foreach compares the roles of the user with " " ... the system displays the LoginView.

Comment: You say they are logged in.  While that may be true, are they in the groups listed in the attribute call: `[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager,...")]`?

Comment: I didn't know that I should add the users with their roles to a group... I have a stored procedure to get from the db the roleList of the user who logs in and I compare them to this.Roles ...  Could you please explain how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by commenting this line:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        //filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

Now the roles of the logged in user are well compared to the defined roles in

[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin,Manager,...")]

The application displays the requested view except if the user doesn't have the right.